# Download shapefiles from arcgis.com

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, download

I'd like to download a shapefile of  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=60d9607abda24d33b357aa0c3623899a . I did an open records request for that and got the following response:

> Please let us know if the following link satisfies your request.
> https://services.arcgis.com/0L95CJ0VTaxqcmED/arcgis/rest/services/ELEVATION_lake_bathymetry_2009/FeatureServer

Unless there's a way to download that data that I am unaware of then the answer to their question is no. I want an offline copy. I'd like to import it into MySQL with ogr2ogr and isolate certain areas and tabulate certain statistics with bulk data from that, etc.

I can pursue the matter further with them if there is no way to download it but if it's just a matter of me not knowing how to use arcgis.com then they're probably not the best resource for what is effectively customer support.

Comment: You seem to be using "shapefile" as a generic term for geodata. While a web service can certainly be copied into a shapefile in a myriad of ways, it is *not* a shapefile, so any searches which focus on that keyword are likely to fail. Try searching on "download feature service arcgis"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `ogr2ogr` you can just read the data directly, no need to export to shapefile and risk messing up the field names because of the shapefile (dbf) limitations.

Based on the examples in the OGR documentation for [esrijson](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html#example) and  [mysql](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mysql.html), something like the following might get you started:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:connectionstring "https://services.arcgis.com/0L95CJ0VTaxqcmED/arcgis/rest/services/ELEVATION_lake_bathymetry_2009/FeatureServer/0/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json"
```